# How to remove a character from Solr's Standard Tokenizer?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a new SOLR index where the Standard Tokenizer works great.

There is one new use case where we want it to not split by hyphens, and we want to be able to index and search `en-us`, but it's currently being split by the hyphen.

We use

```
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="30"/>
```

Is there a way to either:

A) Have the Standard Tokenizer include hyphens, or

B) Recreate the Standard Tokenizer with different rules?

Comment: How do you want to process other hyphens? Are localization identifiers the only ones you want to keep, or do you want to keep other words separated by hyphens? (i.e. `Alcatel-Lucent` and similar).

Comment: @MatsLindh I'd want to keep hyphens in general, except when followed/preceded by whitespace. The `en-us` was just en example, but could also be `words-words`

Comment: Using a Whitespace Tokenizer and [then a WordDelimiterGraphFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterGraphFilter) seems like a more configurable option for what you want to achieve. In particular, you can use the `types` argument to define `-` as a numeric or alpha character, and then use a regex filter to remove `-` at the beginning or end of tokens. Would that work?

Comment: How did you solve this? Would maybe use of solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory before and after the tokenizer work?